# An error with in the execution of an ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have been a really big fan of stackoverflow(which led me to ask the question here and not anywhere else), anyway, without further ado...
While creating a shop system, I planned to implement an ajax which buys the item on the fly. Now This is how the loop for retrieving items looks like:

```
    <?php
                    $shop_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sector0_item WHERE 1");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($shop_query);
                    While ($shop_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($shop_query)){

                ?>
                    <div id="shop_main">
                        <div class = 'item_img'>
                            <a><img src = "http://images.wikia.com/dofus/images/4/4e/Discovery_Potion.png" height = '100px'/></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item_buy">
                            <a><center>Price: <?php echo number_format($shop_fetch['item_price']);?></center><br /></a>
                            <a>Quantity: <input type = 'text' size = '9' id = 'itemquantity'/><br /></a>
                            <a><p>Point requirement: <?php echo number_format($shop_fetch['item_pt_req']);?></p></a>
                            <a><input type = 'button' id = 'buy' value = 'buy'/></a><span id = 'buy_status'></span>

                        </div>
                            <a><h3><?php echo $shop_fetch['item_name'];?></h3></a>
                            <a><p><?php echo $shop_fetch['item_desc'];?></p></a>
                            <a>Item Type: <font color = 'green'><?php echo $shop_fetch['item_class'];?></font></a>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

However, my ajax seems to act really weird. My implementation was to show a loading gif image.
Script:

```
                        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
                                $('#buy').click (function(){
                                    var quantity = $('#itemquantity').val();
                                    $('#buy_status').html('<img src = "http://www.antibodyresource.com/theme/js/ajax-loader.gif" height = 20px;/>');

                                });
                            </script>
```

The problem is, Only one button shows the circle when clicked. Does the position of the script cause this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i didn't get you . "Only one button shows the circle when clicked" what does its mean ??

Comment: Suppose the layout has the following
item_1 (buy)
item_2 (buy)
The loading gif appears only at clicking the first but not the second. Probably because of the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one item with a given id.  When you have multiple elements with the same id, it is indeterminate which one will be returned, but it will usually be the first item only.

If you want multiple buy buttons and want to assign them all the same jQuery event handler, then use a common class name instead of an id.

---

If you are loading content dynamically and you want event handlers to work for that content, then you need to use delegated event handling.

In jQuery, that is generally done with either `.on()` or `.delegate()`.  The basic idea is that you pick a static parent object that is not dynamically loaded (perhaps the parent of show_main) and bind the event to that object and then pass the selector of the dynamic element like this (note, I've changed from an id to a class to identify the buy button):

```
$(staticParentSelector).on('click', '.buyButton', function() {
    $(this).closest(".item_buy").find(".buy_status").html('<img src = "http://www.antibodyresource.com/theme/js/ajax-loader.gif" height = 20px;/>');
})
```

Comment: Well, I tried this part, didn't really work so well; Maybe because I tried the onClick attrib. I followed the advise of classes, however, when I click any button, the entire set of buttons has the loading image shown. Doesn't affect the interaction with the DB though. I changed the #buy and the #buy_status

Comment: @KhalidOkiely - you are slowly explaining what you are trying to do.  Now that I understand that you want to add the gif image just to the button that was clicked, I've modified my answer to do that.  It assumes you are using classes `buy_button`, `buy_status` and `item_buy`.

Comment: I will take a look at that, while I may have to rewrite another code, I will try to keep your trend. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. It's hard to tell from the sample, but is there an iterator that creates a list of available items? If so, you shouldn't be using IDs which are meant to be unique. If there's really only one `#buy` then you're fine, though.
2. When content is updated with Ajax, you're going to lose bindings. Assuming the item related to the `#buy` button gets replaced with other items, you're better off with a delegated event:

```js
// not in an inline script, but just once, ideally in your main JS file
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper').on('click', '#buy', (function(){
    var quantity = $('#itemquantity').val();
    $('#buy_status').html('<img src = "http://www.antibodyresource.com/theme/js/ajax-loader.gif" height = 20px;/>');
  });
})
```

Where `#wrapper` is some ancestor higher up in the DOM tree that is never destroyed by the Ajax event.

Answer (score 0):

id is unique value - on html page each id must have unique value. Use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside `$(document).ready()`. So its:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#buy').click( function(){
         // do something here
    });
});
```

Also, you may want to list to jfriend00's advice on IDs.